# Data not showing in C# RichTextBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, richtextbox

I have a Sql Server connected to a C# form application which displays data strings. On the Sql Server side the data is saved as varChar(MAX) in all three instances. I would just like to display the data onto a RichTextBox on the form. The data is only showing a limited amount of the original data (coming out as incomplete) in the first RichTextBox (DataQualityTextBox) and it is not showing on the second and third RichTextBoxes (LoadFailureTextBox, and LoadPerformanceTextBox).

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);

                // POPULATING THE DATA QUALITY TAB
                Query = "SELECT " + notes_field1 + ", "+ notes_field2 + ", " + notes_field3 + " FROM  "+ database +" " +
                        " WHERE RunDate = '" + formattedDate + "'" +
                        " AND PackageName = '" + tdwl + "'" +
                        " AND Instance = '" + instance + "'; ";

                SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                SqlDataReader myReader;

                try
                {
                    conDataBase.Open();
                    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        DataQualityTextBox.Text = myReader[0].ToString();
                        LoadFailureTextBox.Text = myReader[1].ToString();
                        LoadPerformanceTextBox.Text = myReader[2].ToString();
                    }
                    conDataBase.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: This *replaces* all the text on each loop of the rows, is that what you want? (if not use `.AppendText`) - `LoadFailureTextBox.Text = myReader[0].ToString();` should presumably be `LoadFailureTextBox.Text = myReader[1].ToString();`

Comment: Yes corrected. What I want is to read the data from the Sql Server database and display that on the RichTextBox

Comment: Have you enabled MultiLine text on all the textboxes?

Comment: Yes MultiLine text is set to True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        DataQualityTextBox.Text += myReader[0].ToString();
                        LoadFailureTextBox.Text += myReader[1].ToString();
                        LoadPerformanceTextBox.Text += myReader[2].ToString();
                    }
```

or

```
while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        DataQualityTextBox.AppendText(myReader[0].ToString());
                        LoadFailureTextBox.AppendText(myReader[1].ToString());
                        LoadPerformanceTextBox.AppendText( myReader[2].ToString());
                    }
```

It will Also be a good idea to use parameters in your query instead of concatenating strings

Comment: *Always* use `AppendText` I would say; its far superior as it inserts.

Comment: Yes works well now however when I have "NULL" values from the DB I get no values on the second and third RichTextBox, why is this do you think?